# iterator erase (iterator first, iterator last) doesn't work under Visual C++ 2010 Express

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I've found a problem while writing code under Visual C++ 2010 Express. When executing last line I get a runtime error "vector iterator not dereferencable". What is wrong with the code below?

```
vector<int> vec (5, 1001);

vector<int>::iterator begin = vec.begin();
vector<int>::iterator end = vec.begin();

begin++; //std::advance(begin, 1); gives the same result
end++; end++; end++; //std::advance(end, 3); gives the same result

cout << (*begin) << endl;
cout << (*end) << endl;
begin = vec.erase(begin, end);
cout << (*begin) << endl;              //It doesn't work
```

This code works under gcc.
When elements are erased one by one it works in VC++ 2010 Express too.

Is it a bug in VC++ 2010 Express?

Comment: no problem with VC++ 2013

Comment: Looks like it.  Odds are `vec.erase(a,b)` returns `a`, as without debug checks that would work, even though technically `a` was invalidated (as it now refers to a different element).  I'd take a look at the source and see if that is what is happening (probably by stepping through it).

Comment: No problem with VC++ 2010 Professional either. Version = "Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86" . Compiled and run from command line with "cl test.cpp".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your not using SP1 then this [VC10 bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/545013)
might have hit you, there is also some kind of workaround listed there.

Comment: I confirm that it works when: 1. compiling with release configuration without SP1. 2. It works in debug configuration too with SP1. The case is solved.

Comment: "If you often find yourself suspecting that the compiler or the hardware made an error, you’re still in the realm of superstition. Only about 5 percent of all errors are hardware, compiler, or operating-system errors", the Code Complete book. This time you got lucky...